# My android service working fine on other devices, but on some devices

Tags: android, service, background

My android service is working fine on some devices. On other devices, it's show running in "Running Applications" but it's not working and it's taking up 0 mb RAM. I have tried this solution too.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
    screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);



    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    registerReceiver(timeTickReceiver, screenStateFilter);

    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Please tell me how can I fix this

Comment: did you run any test case to confirm its not running ?

Comment: Yes i try to toast in service, but nothing is working. I found this only in one device.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);



//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


registerReceiver(timeTickReceiver, screenStateFilter);

// try removing this line commented below
// super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

//return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

check my comment